# Why can I only access mongodb's GridFS under test database?

Tags: mongodb

I've added a file to mongodb's GridFS using:

```
mongofiles put <the file>
```

Now I can see it by by running the command:

```
db.fs.chunks.find()
```

Only if I'm using the test database, when I use a custom database, the second command returns nothing. Is mongodb using test as the default database for storing files? Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: I get it now. When I run the first command it uses test as default database since I didn't specify any. To specify my database I have to use -d flag like:

    mongofiles -d <database name>

now when I use my database, db.fs.chunks.find() returns something useful. Unfortunately I can't answer my own question since I have yet a small reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is mongodb using test as the default database for storing files?

Yes, `test` is the default database.

> Is there a way to specify this?

Yes. This will vary by driver. If you're doing it from the command line you can connect to `servername:port/databasename`. There's also typically a `-d` option for specifying the DB name.